# model lose changes on database update in Entity framework 6

Tags: entity-framework-6

I am using Entity framework 6.

I need some additional properties for some table.Can it be possible to add those properties  into a class created by Entity framework 6?

I am trying to do that, but when I modify the  database and update the model, it will lose my changes.

Is there any way to do it in Entity framework 6?

Or do I have to create a partial class?

Answer (score 1):

All classes generated by designer are partial. If you want to add your own non-persisted properties you must create your own partial part for that.